# Write to a file and read it simultaneously, reading by spreadsheet viewer like excel not the same code?

Tags: c++-cli

Well the thing is my code writes some data to a spreadsheet file, but if anyone tries to open it "File Is being used by some other process" error appears... to work around this I created a temp file write to it blah blah blah ... but this does not seem like a good method, is there a method where I would be able to write to the  spreadsheet file through my program and still be able to "VIEW ONLY" the spreadsheet simultaneously...

Answer (score 0):

Use [the four-parameter version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) of `System::IO::File::Open()`, it allows you to specify a `FileShare` so you can allow reading while your file is open for writing.

Be mindful of the synchronization issues that can cause, however: One process could try reading the file while it is in an inconsistent state.